# How do I get all leads that are updated after certain date using Marketo Rest v1 API?

Tags: marketo

I am trying to figure out a way to get all the modified(or created) leads after a certain time stamp.

Looks like, the marketo SOAP API has this updatedAt filter but not their REST API.

Is there any workaround?

Marketo SOAP API: http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/soap/getmultipleleads/

Marketo REST API: https://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-multiple-leads-by-filter-type/

Answer (score 0):

This API retrieves change data value for leads(updated) .

Hope it will help you.

[Get Lead Changes](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-lead-changes)

[Get Paging Token for particular day](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-paging-token/)